# Updating Ubuntu 14.04 kernel to prevent SpectreAndMeltdown via bash : doesn't upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, upgrade

I have updated my server with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But after the upgrade when i :

```
 uname -a
```

I still get:

```
Linux xxxxx 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Shouldn't it have updated to the newer versions:

```
3.13.0.139.xxx
```

As seen on this security notice:

https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3524-1/

EDIT:

Rebooting after this doesn't help. `uname -a` returns the same as above.

```
ls /boot
```

returns:

```
System.map-3.13.0-139-generic  config-3.13.0-32-generic       memtest86+.elf
System.map-3.13.0-32-generic   grub                           memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.13.0-139-generic         initrd.img-3.13.0-139-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic
abi-3.13.0-32-generic          initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic   vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
config-3.13.0-139-generic      memtest86+.bin
```

Just want to make sure I am not vulnerable to these attacks.

Comment: You need to reboot it after the upgrade.

Comment: If you `ls /boot` before you reboot, you should see both the old and new kernels.

Comment: I have rebooted but is stays the same. Doing a  `ls /boot` gives me: `System.map-3.13.0-139-generic  config-3.13.0-32-generic       memtest86+.elf
System.map-3.13.0-32-generic   grub                           memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.13.0-139-generic         initrd.img-3.13.0-139-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic
abi-3.13.0-32-generic          initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic   vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
config-3.13.0-139-generic      memtest86+.bin`

Comment: After you rebooted, what does `uname -a` return?

Comment: Still the same: `Linux xxxxxx 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Dependencies are a bit conservative, you have to install it explicitly naming it.

Comment: Can you give an example of the syntax to install it as a dependency? Thanks!

Comment: Don’t let arbitrary people run arbitrary code on your system.

Comment: I agree. Sec 101. I would only use it as a lead. I would never just copy paste something into the console without knowing what it did.

Comment: Would you run `apt-cache search linux` and post the output? I am using Debian cannot give you the exact command without that output

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I totally forgot I was SSH'ing into a VM and i was using DigitalOceans Legacy Kernel management.

Following their own upgrade guide to use the Grubloader I got the Kernel updated.

1. power down from the VM with

   ```
   sudo poweroff
   ```
2. from the droplet interface choose ( if present ) <kbd>kernel</kbd> -> select the kernel: <kbd>Grubloader</kbd>
3. Then via the interface select <kbd>Power</kbd> -> <kbd>Power on</kbd>
4. Now you can check kernel with

   ```
   uname -ir
   ```

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-update-a-digitalocean-server-s-kernel)